# how to deploy specific docker container just by docker run?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise

1. `mkdir -p data/{sentry,postgres}` - Make our local database and sentry config directories.
   This directory is bind-mounted with postgres so you don't lose state!
2. `docker-compose run --rm web config generate-secret-key` - Generate a secret key.
   Add it to `docker-compose.yml` in `base` as `SENTRY_SECRET_KEY`.
3. `docker-compose run --rm web upgrade` - Build the database.
   Use the interactive prompts to create a user account.
4. `docker-compose up -d` - Lift all services (detached/background mode).
5. Access your instance at `localhost:9000`!

I'm new to docker.
I tried to run sentry container locally, succeeded.
But when I was trying to deploy it on a cloud container service platform,I met some problems.

The platform just provide one way to run docker: `docker run xxx` , unlike aws which can use cli.
So how could I deploy on that platform? Thanks.

Additionally,I must use that platform cause it's my company's product lol.

Comment: Go with Azure Cloud premises , they provide the service called Docker container as a Service. So please see there documentation and go with trial period of Azure and try to run . your compose yaml file according to the step wise.

Comment: Thanks, but if I must use that platform because it's my company's product lol